# Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" on Git Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, reportviewer

I got an azure website configure and a git repository linked, so when i make push to my repo it gets deployed on azure, the thing is that the deployment failed with this message:

> D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common". Check to make sure the
>   assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code,
>   you may get compilation errors.

I've set all the corresponding Dlls to copy local but still is failing, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this i need to install the Microsoft.ReportViewer references through nugget, so when i push to my repository, azure could download the necessary references